# How to start teamspeak 3 on boot, ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, init.d

So I'm quite new to linux but I'm starting to understand it. I have a Ubuntu Server 12.04 system, fresh install, and I installed a teamspeak 3 server on it:

```
$ sudo useradd teamspeak
(provided user info and password)
$ su teamspeak
(entered password)
$ cd /home/teamspeak
$ wget http://ftp.4players.de/pub/hosted/ts3/releases/3.0.10.3/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64-3.0.10.3.tar.gz
(download teamspeak.tar.gz)
$ tar -zxvf teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64-3.0.10.3.tar.gz
(unpacked the file to teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64)
$ mv teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64 server
(server is no located in /home/teamspeak/server)
$ cd ./server
$ ./ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh createinifile=1
(initialized the server)
$ ./ts3server_startscript.sh start
(started the server)
```

Now when I reboot my server (e.g. `$ sudo reboot`) the server doesn't start up. Obviously because I haven't configured anything in `/etc/init.d` but I have no idea how to do this.

I want the server to start like it does with the `/home/teamspeak/server/ts3server_startscript.sh start` script, ran by the user `teamspeak`.

I followed several guides but they didn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend creating an Upstart script.

First you want to create the script itself: `sudo nano /etc/init/ts-server.conf`

Copy and paste this skeleton and make any changes you need:

```
# description "start and stop the TS server"

console log # Log events to console

exec start-stop-daemon --start --chdir /home/teamspeak/server/ --chuid teamspeak \
    --exec /home/teamspeak/server/ts3server_startscript.sh start

 start on runlevel [2345] # Tell when to start
stop on runlevel [^2345] # Tell when to stop

respawn # Block excess respawn
respawn limit 20 5 # Ditto
```

Save that file, go to `/home/teamspeak/server/` and create a file `ts3server_upstart.sh`
Contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/teamspeak/server/ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

Save, mark it as execuatable, done! It'll start on boot, and can be manually started/stopped/restarted using `sudo service ts-server start`, `sudo service ts-server stop`, and `sudo service ts-server restart`, respectively.

EDIT: This may not actually STOP TeamSpeak. I do not know enough about TS and starting to tell you whether it will or will not.

Comment: Can you explain what you did. I'm a bit of a noob and I like to understand what I'm doing. Thanks for your answer though, I'll give it a go..

Comment: Basically the first part is creating something known as Upstart, Ubuntu's program for launching stuff at boot. The second part is creating a script for Upstart to launch. I will edit with comments.

Comment: Thanks for editing with comments, it doesn't quite work.. When I reboot the server, ssh and execute htop, I don't see a process executing from `teamspeak`, neither do I see a process that is the teamspeak server, and I cannot connect to it from my desktop/laptop. When I run `ts3server_startscript.sh start` I can, and when I run `sudo ./ts3server_startscript.sh stop` it stops. When I run `sudo service ts-server start|stop|restart` it says it starts but doesn't and gives errors with stop or restart: `stop: Unknown instance:` and `stop: Unknown instance:
ts-server start/running, process 1344`.

Comment: hmm. that is interesting,

Comment: edited post. try the new version.

Comment: Doesnt work either.. I'm guessing the problem is at my end, I'll start over from the beginning. Thanks for helping me

Comment: I managed to get it to work using a simpler version of your script. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is the upstart script I use, mostly a rip off of Mew's:

```
description "Teamspeak 3"

console log # Log events to console

setuid teamspeak
setgid teamspeak

exec /opt/teamspeak/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh

start on runlevel [2345] # Tell when to start
stop on runlevel [^2345] # Tell when to stop

respawn # Block excess respawn
respawn limit 20 5 # Ditto
```

It requires upstart 1.4 or higher for `setuid`/`setgid`, but Ubuntu 12.04 provides that. If you don't have that you can just change the exec line to be `exec su -s /bin/sh -c /opt/teamspeak/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh teamspeak` instead.

The main difference is that it uses `ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh` instead, which doesn't fork. `ts3server_startscript.sh` is meant to be used as a sort of init script so it forks - which isn't necessary for upstart. When used with upstart it means that you can't do commands like `service ts-server status` or even `service ts-server stop`. With this script you can.

Answer (score -1):

I have followed step by step in this tutorial, everything is describe, how to install and configure TeamSpeak3 server with MySQL - MariaDB on Debian/Ubuntu.
http://terminal28.com/how-to-install-and-configure-teamspeak3-server-linux-debian-ubuntu/

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.